# Ubuntu 16.04 on laptop with AMD graphic card?

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics

Currently I'm using 14.04 and have a Lenovo which has the integrated Intel chipset GPU and a dedicated Radeon HD8600. Since they claimed that they are known issues with the fglrx driver I want to know if I can use it as a normal user. Thing is that in the additional drivers the graphic card is set to use the open source driver, not fglrx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04 (fresh install) and yes, you can use the normal open source driver (installed by default) with no problems! :)

I too have an integrated AMD graphics solution (HD7310).

Fglrx as far as I know is proprietary drivers from AMD. If you are using your laptop to play video games then I would recommend to stick to 14.04 for fglrx drivers as they are optimized for games from what I have discovered.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS is running fine on my laptop.